# File comparison report

Tags: excel, vba

The code below searches and compares the file names between two folders (including subfolders) reporting how many duplicates there are between folders. Subfolder names are identical. 
I need to prohibit to comare files from different subfolders. I mean macro should only compare files in subfolders with the same subfolder names even if in other folders there are files with the same file names.
Can anyone help?

Example:

```
 **folder1**       **folder2**
first_folder  vs  first_folder   
  1.xml                 1.xml
  2.xml                 2.xml

second_folder vs  second_folder
  1.xml                 1.xml
```

The macro should not search for and compare 1.xml file between first_folder and second_folder. Only files from the same folder name should be compared.

Thank you in advance.

```
Sub CompareContentsofTwoFolders()
     Dim fcount As Variant
     Dim pth1 As String, pth2 As String
     Dim r1 As Single, r2 As Single
     Dim arrd() As Variant
     Dim arru() As Variant
     ReDim arrd(0 To 5, 0)
     ReDim arru(0 To 2, 0)
     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
         .Show
         pth1 = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
     End With
     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
         .Show
         pth2 = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
     End With
     Sheets.Add
     Set x = ActiveSheet
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     x.Range("A1") = "Duplicate files"
     x.Range("A2") = "Path"
     x.Range("B2") = "File name"
     x.Range("C2") = "Size"
     x.Range("D2") = "Path"
     x.Range("E2") = "File name"
     x.Range("F2") = "Size"
     x.Range("A:F").Font.Bold = False
     x.Range("A1:F2").Font.Bold = True
     Recursive pth1

     Lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     x.Range("A2:C" & Lrow).Sort Key1:=x.Range("B1"), Header:=xlYes
     arr1 = x.Range("A3:C" & Lrow).Value
     x.Range("A3:C" & Lrow).Clear
     Recursive pth2
     Lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     x.Range("A2:C" & Lrow).Sort Key1:=x.Range("B1"), Header:=xlYes
     arr2 = x.Range("A3:C" & Lrow).Value
     x.Range("A3:C" & Lrow).Clear
     x.Range("H1") = "Total number of files in Folder 1: " 'Modified No.1
     x.Range("I1") = UBound(arr1, 1)
     x.Range("H2") = "Total number of files in Folder 2: " 'Modified No.2
     x.Range("I2") = UBound(arr2, 1)
     For r1 = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
         chk = False
             If r1 > 1 Then
                 If arr1(r1, 2) = arr1(r1 - 1, 2) Then
                     For r3 = UBound(arrd, 2) To LBound(arrd, 2) Step -1
                         If arrd(2, r3) <> "" And arrd(1, r3) <> arr1(r1, 2) Then Exit For
                         If arrd(1, r3) = arr1(r1, 2) Then
                             If r3 = UBound(arrd, 2) Then ReDim Preserve arrd(UBound(arrd, 1), UBound(arrd, 2) + 1)
                             arrd(0, r3 + 1) = arr1(r1, 1)
                             arrd(1, r3 + 1) = arr1(r1, 2)
                             arrd(2, r3 + 1) = arr1(r1, 3)
                             ReDim Preserve arrd(UBound(arrd, 1), UBound(arrd, 2) + 1)
                             Exit For
                         End If
                     Next r3
                     For r3 = UBound(arru, 2) To LBound(arru, 2) Step -1
                         If arru(2, r3) <> "" And arru(1, r3) <> arr1(r1, 2) Then Exit For
                         If arru(1, r3) = arr1(r1, 2) Then
                             If r3 = UBound(arru, 2) Then ReDim Preserve arru(UBound(arru, 1), UBound(arru, 2) + 1)
                             arru(0, r3 + 1) = arr1(r1, 1)
                             arru(1, r3 + 1) = arr1(r1, 2)
                             arru(2, r3 + 1) = arr1(r1, 3)
                             ReDim Preserve arru(UBound(arru, 1), UBound(arru, 2) + 1)
                             Exit For
                         End If
                     Next r3
                     GoTo jmp
                 End If
             End If
         For r2 = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
             If arr2(r2, 2) = arr1(r1, 2) Then
                 If chk = False Then
                     arrd(0, UBound(arrd, 2)) = arr1(r1, 1)
                     arrd(1, UBound(arrd, 2)) = arr1(r1, 2)
                     arrd(2, UBound(arrd, 2)) = arr1(r1, 3)
                 Else
                     arrd(0, UBound(arrd, 2)) = ""
                     arrd(1, UBound(arrd, 2)) = ""
                     arrd(2, UBound(arrd, 2)) = ""
                 End If
                 arrd(3, UBound(arrd, 2)) = arr2(r2, 1)
                 arrd(4, UBound(arrd, 2)) = arr2(r2, 2)
                 arrd(5, UBound(arrd, 2)) = arr2(r2, 3)
                 arr2(r2, 1) = ""
                 ReDim Preserve arrd(UBound(arrd, 1), UBound(arrd, 2) + 1)
                 chk = True
             End If
         Next r2
         If chk = False Then
                 arru(0, UBound(arru, 2)) = arr1(r1, 1)
                 arru(1, UBound(arru, 2)) = arr1(r1, 2)
                 arru(2, UBound(arru, 2)) = arr1(r1, 3)
                 ReDim Preserve arru(UBound(arru, 1), UBound(arru, 2) + 1)
         End If
jmp:
     Next r1
     For r2 = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
         If arr2(r2, 1) <> "" Then
             arru(0, UBound(arru, 2)) = arr2(r2, 1)
             arru(1, UBound(arru, 2)) = arr2(r2, 2)
             arru(2, UBound(arru, 2)) = arr2(r2, 3)
             ReDim Preserve arru(UBound(arru, 1), UBound(arru, 2) + 1)
         End If
     Next r2
     x.Range("A3").Resize(UBound(arrd, 2) + 1, UBound(arrd, 1) + 1) = Application.Transpose(arrd)
     x.Range("H3") = "Total number of duplicate files: " 'Modified No.3
     x.Range("I3") = UBound(arrd, 2)
     x.Range("H4") = "Total number of unique files: " 'Modified No.4
     x.Range("I4") = UBound(arru, 2)
     x.Range("A" & UBound(arrd, 2) + 3) = "Unique files"
     x.Range("A" & UBound(arrd, 2) + 4) = "Path"
     x.Range("B" & UBound(arrd, 2) + 4) = "File name"
     x.Range("C" & UBound(arrd, 2) + 4) = "Size"
     x.Range("A" & UBound(arrd, 2) + 3 & ":C" & UBound(arrd, 2) + 4).Font.Bold = True
     x.Range("A" & UBound(arrd, 2) + 5).Resize(UBound(arru, 2) + 1, UBound(arru, 1) + 1) = Application.Transpose(arru)

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     End Sub
     Sub Recursive(FolderPath As String)
     Dim Value As String, Folders() As String
     Dim Folder As Variant, a As Long
     ReDim Folders(0)
     If Right(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then Exit Sub
     Value = Dir(FolderPath, &H1F)
     Do Until Value = ""
         If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then

         Else
             If GetAttr(FolderPath & Value) = 16 Or GetAttr(FolderPath & Value) = 48 Then
                 Folders(UBound(Folders)) = Value
                 ReDim Preserve Folders(UBound(Folders) + 1)
             Else
                 If Right(Value, 4) = ".xml" Then
                    Lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Lrow) = FolderPath
                    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Lrow) = Value
                    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Lrow) = FileLen(FolderPath & Value)
                End If
             End If
         End If
         Value = Dir
     Loop
     For Each Folder In Folders
         Recursive FolderPath & Folder & "\"
     Next Folder
 End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like a *"here is my code please fix it"* question. Also [“Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). I recommend to read [ask] to improve your question and include in your question where exactly you got stuck (or errors) and what your difficulties are while tying to fix it. Reading [mcve] might also help you to ask a better question.

Comment: Why don't you just compare the full filepath? Then you can't compare files in a different folder?

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation but unfortunately this is not "my code", I do not know VB, I just found it and changed a bit where I could understand.

Comment: Sam, ithis could work, but unfortunately I do not know how to do this...

Comment: The thing is that people here can kindly help/assist you fixing your issues yourself. But the one who needs to fix it is still you. You work, we assist. • If you cannot do it it's probably a better way to hire and pay someone who does it for you. Let me try to explain it with an example: If you cannot drive the car at all you need to pay for the taxi or bus. But if you have a specific question like *"How do I put in the reverse gear in a Mercedes Benz?"* we can answer that.

Comment: Pᴇʜ, I'm pretty sure that you are experienced person here and you know what you are doing and advising and I respect your point of you, but I think that the change that is need to be done in this code is not global. Of course otherwise my attitude to the problem was appropriate. If I'm wrong and this is a huge work here (not case of 1-2 strings) then sorry for bothering. But if the change is not sighnificant any hint could help. I can try to change the code myself, but I need to know where exactly:)